# Pandas how to output distinct values in column based on duplicate in another column

Tags: python, pandas

Here an example:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'product':['1','1','1','2','2','2','3','3','3','4','4','4','5','5','5'],
    'value':['a','a','a','a','a','b','a','b','a','b','b','b','a','a','a']
})

      product value
0        1     a
1        1     a
2        1     a
3        2     a
4        2     a
5        2     b
6        3     a
7        3     b
8        3     a
9        4     b
10       4     b
11       4     b
12       5     a
13       5     a
14       5     a
```

I need to output:

```
1 a
4 b
5 a
```

Because 'value' values for distinct 'product' values all are same
I'm sorry for bad English

Comment: The question is not clear. Why `2 a, 3 a, 2 b` and so on are not in output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need this

```
m=df.groupby('product')['value'].transform('nunique')
df.loc[m==1].drop_duplicates(). reset_index(drop=True)
```

**Output**

```
   product  value
0   1        a
1   4        b
2   5        a
```

**Details**
`df.groupby('product')['value'].transform('nunique')` returns a series as below

```
0     1
1     1
2     1
3     2
4     2
5     2
6     2
7     2
8     2
9     1
10    1
11    1
12    1
13    1
14    1
```

where the numbers of the number of unique values in each group. Then we use `df.loc` to get only the rows in which this value is 1, so, the groups with unique values.

The we drop duplicates since you need only the group & its unique value.

Comment: I used your dataframe & ran a check. It works. What error are you getting?

Comment: Yea got it. Sorry. Can you explain for a little how it works?

Comment: Explanation added.

Comment: If the answer helped you, consider up-voting & accepting the answer.

Answer (score 1):

If I undestand correctly your question, this simple code is for your:

```
distinct_prod_df = df.drop_duplicates(['product'])
```

and gives:

```
   product value
0        1     a
3        2     a
6        3     a
9        4     b
12       5     a
```

Comment: Yea but product 2 have values a a b. I need product if all values are same.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
mask = df.groupby('product').apply(lambda x: x.nunique() == 1)
df = df[mask].drop_duplicates()
```